# removing files from C code

Tags: c

I have to remove few hundreds of files inside my C code. I use "remove" in a loop. Is there any faster way to do it than using "remove"? I ask this because I can't give wildchars using "remove".

Comment: Why don't you pipe the result of a ls inside the loop so that you won't have to type all the names

Comment: The issue is, there are 50000 files in that directory. I have to delete only a few of them when required. "remove" works fine for me but it takes a while to finish it off. I'm looking for something faster. I don't want to invoke shell commands from "C" if I can do the same in "C" itself.

Comment: Could you use python? :)

Comment: That ain't an option. I'm working on an embedded platform where it's space constraint to put any new packages in.

Comment: Why is this question about C programming at risk of being migrated to Super User? I've just seen a few questions like this while reviewing and it doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't a quicker way than using [`remove()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/remove.html) - or [`unlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) on POSIX systems - in a loop.

The system `rm` command does that too - at least in the simple, non-recursive case where the names are given on the command line.  The shell expands the metacharacters, and `rm` (in)famously goes along deleting what it was told to delete, unaware of the disastrous `*.*` notation that was used on the command line. (In the recursive case, it uses a function such as [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) to traverse the directory structure in depth-first order and repeated calls to `unlink()` to remove the files and [`rmdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html) to remove the (now-empty) directories.)

POSIX does provide functions ([`glob()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html) and [`wordexp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html)) to generate lists of file names from metacharacters as used in the (POSIX) shell, plus [`fnmatch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html) to see whether a name matches a pattern.

Comment: Isn't `*` the same as `*.*`, or is there some subtle difference? When people mention an `rm` apocalypse they always seem to use `*.*`

Comment: Under Windows `*.*` was needed; on Unix, `*` is sufficient (actually, more devastating than `*.*` since the simple `*` matches more names).  I marginally debated which to use and (for better or worse) chose `*.*`.  Both are bad news.  (And the worst `rm` cataclysm I've seen was removing the account for a temporary user created with root `/` as their home directory; the 'remove user' command removed everything under their home directory.  It is surprising how long a system can run after losing crucial files.  Fortunately, it was a brand new system and there was a backup from the day before.)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can generate the file names without any issue. My only concern was issuing the "remove" command faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `system` to spawn a shell which would do the * expansion for you. This would probably not run any faster than just calling unlink() in a loop, though, because it would have to spawn a shell (start a new process). But it would be easier to code.